# How to save file in the same path of uploaded file, PHP?

Tags: php, forms, upload, path, watermark

Use PHP , my concept is:
User upload image by submit form, then script overlay logo watermark. I want to save the modified image to the same location of original image (on user's computer). My code now is something like this:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="watermark.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Select file:
<input type="file" name="uploadfile"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

How to know the path of original file to save the modified image in the same location?

Answer (score 1):

You can't save it directly on user's computer (using HTML) as that would be a violation of - everything. Instead, you can provide the file for download after modification. Provided, you are using GD for watermarking, the code is simple (but not perfect and should be considered just a lead):

```
// perform some ops with $img

Header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
Header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);

imagejpeg($img);

imagedestroy($img);
```

Comment: My bad luck! I know how to perform the watermarked image, just want to know how to save the file to the same location. BTW thanks Miroslav.

Comment: As I said, I'm developing websites for a years and I can't think of a direct way, not by HTML means and I'm not really sure if you can do it with Java Applet or Flash controller of sorts. It would be such a violation of privacy and security to allow arbitrary site to replace content of your filesystem...

Comment: I try to do by this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631624/find-path-of-file-to-be-uploaded), but it return **C:\\fakepath\\xxx.jpg**.

Comment: It's not about getting the path (you can create onsubmit handler on form and pass the path to hidden text field), but about saving the file again to this very path... those double slashes are easy to remove (str_replace), tho.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy. I have done that. When the user uploads the images, instead of just taking the images, create a hidden field to store the whole path. Now, either leave this path on user's PC in cookie or store it with you. At the time to returning, use the customized save as dialog box and insert that path before the file.

Comment: Any example or code, @divanshu? I try to do this by adding <input type="hidden" name="filepath" id="filepath"/> to the form and also add ...onchange="document.getElementById('filepath').value=this.value;"  to the element <input type="file"> , but it return "fakepath"....

Comment: I follow the instruction in [Find Path of File to be Uploaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631624/find-path-of-file-to-be-uploaded). It returns **C:\\fakepath\\xxx.jpg** in $_POST['filepath'].